# how to find multiple findings with a single find command? is it possible or not. Any other possibilities/suggestions are much welcomed

Tags: vba, ms-word

From the following code parenthesis and full-stop will be found and replaced.i.e. (2026).=>2026,

But if the following conditions occur code does not find it and leave it as it is.

a.2020)

b.2012).

c.(2015)

```vb
Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory
   
Selection.find.ClearFormatting

Selection.find.Style = ActiveDocument.styles("<Ref_caption_bmk>")

Selection.find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

 With Selection.find
      
         .text = "(\([0-9a-f]{4,5}\))(.)"
        .Replacement.text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    Do While .Execute = True
    charcount = Len(Selection.text)
    Selection.MoveLeft unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    If (Selection.text = "(") Then Selection.Delete
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=charcount - 3
    Selection.MoveRight unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    If (Selection.text = ")") Then Selection.Delete
    If (Selection.text = ".") Then Selection.Delete
    Selection.TypeText text:=","
    charcount = 0
    Loop
  End With
```

Is there any way to find all these conditions within this module itself?

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications are unclear. That said, for what you seem to want, the result can be achieved with a *wildcard* Find/Replace expression no more complex than:

```
Find = ([!a-c][!.])\((20[0-9]{2})\).
Replace = \1\2
```

No VBA code needed.

You should also learn to code properly instead of slavishly using the macro recorder. For example:

```
Sub FR_Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "([!a-c][!.])\((20[0-9]{2})\)."
    .Style = "<Ref_caption_bmk>"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1\2"
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The are many such examples here and on other forums.

Comment: thanks for your code but it'll only find things which is (2000).  But what i need to find is all these occurrences a.(2000). b.(2000) c.2000) d.(2000 e.(2000. f.2000).

Comment: Kindly edit your question to say what you want to achieve. I coded the answer the way I did because of the way you worded your question. Only a trivial change would be required. Did you do any research on *wildcard* Find/Replace?